# VC (win32) or WPF for developing a text editor

Tags: wpf, visual-c++, winapi

I have this confusion to develop this application in Win32 or WPF (.NET). This application primarily consists of a text editor (think of similar to the one in MS OneNote) with lot of customized requirements compared to a general text editor.

I was thinking to use VC to work on this as lots of custom drawing is required. What do you guys suggest? Is WPF is a best deal for this sort of applications? Or Win32 is better to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write any sort of GUI app on Windows, I would recommend not using C++. .NET is much, much better for creating a GUI than all of the various C++ GUI libraries that are on Windows. I could see using WPF for writing an app like OneNote working out fairly well, since WPF is very easily extensible.

Comment: I am not sure whether WPF supports or has apis/libs to develop an editor like the one in OneNote without having make win32 calls?

Comment: The nice thing about WPF is that if it doesn't have a feature built in, it's very easy to add it yourself. IMO it's much easier to make a complex and pretty UI in WPF than in Win32. Maybe do some small test projects in WPF to see if it can do what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a commercial WPF Text Editor you can check out one from ActiPro: http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx

Comment: The user is asking about writing the application in WPF, not using it to edit C#/XAML.